# Как создать application/pkcs7-mime программно?

Tags: c#

Интересует сама стуктура объекта application/pkcs7-mime (.p7m, .p7c). Вопрос в том, как создать объект application/pkcs7-mime без использования System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs?

Answer (score 1):

Есть [спецификация](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2311), там по идее все описано, но не знаю, готовы ли Вы к такому подвигу - я бы не взялся изучать сей документ.

Также можно взять Reflector и декомпилировать классы в `System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs`

Либо, еще вариант: поискать сторонние библиотеки